# NATURAL JOIN does not work properly

Tags: mysql, join, natural-join

I have three tables describes like that:

```
+----------+    +-----------------+    +----------+ 
| products |    | products_stores |    | stores   | 
+----------+    +-----------------+    +----------+ 
| barecode |    | #barecode       |    | storeID  | 
| name     |----| #storeID        |----| location | 
+----------+    | price           |    +----------+ 
                +-----------------+
```

Created them like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `barecode` varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`barecode`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stores` (
  `idStore` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idStore`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_stores` (
  `idStore` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `barecode` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`barecode`) REFERENCES `products`(`barecode`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`idStore`) REFERENCES `stores`(`idStore`)
);
```

I wanted to get all the product and its price with the right store so I tried NATURAL JOIN but it returned nothing (code below 1-). So I tried with only one NATURAL JOIN just to check and it works (code below 2- and 3-).

```
1- SELECT * FROM products NATURAL JOIN products_stores NATURAL JOIN stores;
2- SELECT * FROM products JOIN products_stores NATURAL JOIN stores;
3- SELECT * FROM products NATURAL JOIN products_stores JOIN stores;
```

I do not understand why the "double" NATURAL JOIN does not work. Does anyone can help me through this?
Thanks.

Comment: When you say `does not work`..what does that mean? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Are the column names in the `products_stores` table really `#barecode`, or is the pound symbol just there for emphasis?

Comment: No, it return nothing. An empty table, as described under the creation of the tables.
@Tim: it's really foreign keys, and it works with just one natural join, just not two... Can't understand why

Comment: @TDK:- Your syntax is looking ok and it looks like your table is not having any data to JOIN on.

Comment: @RahulTripathi But I have data. I did not write the insert into. I can get it with other queries like the number 2 and 3 on the  examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your data,here is what the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) has to say about it

> The evaluation of multi-way natural joins differs in a very important
>   way that affects the result of NATURAL or USING joins and that can
>   require query rewriting. Suppose that you have three tables t1(a,b),
>   t2(c,b), and t3(a,c) that each have one row: t1(1,2), t2(10,2), and
>   t3(7,10). Suppose also that you have this NATURAL JOIN on the three
>   tables:
>
> SELECT ... FROM t1 NATURAL JOIN t2 NATURAL JOIN t3; Previously, the
>   left operand of the second join was considered to be t2, whereas it
>   should be the nested join (t1 NATURAL JOIN t2). As a result, the
>   columns of t3 are checked for common columns only in t2, and, if t3
>   has common columns with t1, these columns are not used as equi-join
>   columns. Thus, previously, the preceding query was transformed to the
>   following equi-join:
>
> SELECT ... FROM t1, t2, t3   WHERE t1.b = t2.b AND t2.c = t3.c;
>   That join is missing one more equi-join predicate (t1.a = t3.a). As a
>   result, it produces one row, not the empty result that it should. The
>   correct equivalent query is this:
>
> SELECT ... FROM t1, t2, t3   WHERE t1.b = t2.b AND t2.c = t3.c AND
>   t1.a = t3.a;

In short the second JOIN only checks for the previous table`s column not the WHOLE result of the first JOIN.

One of the reasons that NATURAL JOINs are not recommended,not much control and little to gain.

Comment: Ok, I understand the thing. I'll do it with regular join, I thought natural join was really gainful!